# Использование модуля path Node js при тестировании выдаёт ошибку

Tags: javascript, node.js, jest

При тестировании с помощью jest функции использующей модуль path, а вчастности метод path.join() выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

> TypeError: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an
> instance of Buffer

Вот сам stack trace ошибки
[Ссылка](https://pastebin.com/aAyezkQE)

Как решить эту проблему не могу понять. Судя по всему проблема в том, что метод join определяется как строчный вызываемый на переменной path, в то время как это модуль

```
TypeError: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Buffer

   6 | const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
   7 | const __dirname = dirname(__filename);
>  8 | export const makePath = (paths) => pathTo.join(__dirname, '..', ...paths);
     |                                           ^
   9 | export const getFile = (...paths) => fs.readFileSync(makePath(paths));
  10 |

  at join (src/utils.js:8:43)
  at makePath (src/utils.js:9:54)
  at getFile (src/index.js:43:30)
  at Object.diff (__tests__/gendiff.test.js:12:10)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.549 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
make: *** [Makefile:10: test] Error 1

Comment: Приложите код, в котором возникает ошибка и саму ошибку в виде текста

Comment: проблема не в join, а в том, что вы передаёте в аргумент paths

Comment: ну а где код который вызывает это все?
getFile (src/index.js:43:30),
Object.diff (__tests__/gendiff.test.js:12:10)